# How to match the function name in a function call?

Tags: regular-expressions, symbols

I am trying to extract the function name from a function call. For example:

```el
(let ((str "(test-func"))
  (if (string-match "^(\\s_+" str)
      (message "ok")
    (message "no match")))
```

But this gives `"no match"`.. (For simplicity I reduced `str` to the start of the real string. A real string could be for example `"(test-func a b)"`

I think the problem is the `\s_`   symbol constituent regex..

Comment: In an empty buffer, type `(test-func` -- then type `M-x re-builder` -- then in between the double quotation marks  in the re-builder buffer, type your proposed regexp and see if it works.  If it doesn't, then work on the regexp until re-builder shows the highlighting is correct -- e.g., paste the regexp by abo-abo and see the difference.

Comment: Not answering your question directly: why are you trying to parse the code yourself (instead of using Emacs' own Lisp parser)? Obviously, you can't parse Emacs Lisp with regular grammar, but, again, there might be some legitimate uses, this is why this is posed as a question.

Comment: Quoting from elsewhere, in case it helps clarify this Q&A for anyone: "A "symbol" may contain both word-constituent characters and symbol-constituent characters. But the terms "symbol-constituent [character]" and "word-constituent [character]" themselves are very specifically about their own mutually-exclusive syntax classes, and there is no similar term which refers to a character from *either* syntax class."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
(let ((str "(test-func"))
  (if (string-match "^(\\(?:\\s_\\|\\sw\\)+" str)
      (message "ok")
    (message "no match")))
```

`\\s_` will match stuff like `-`, while `\\sw` will actually match the alnum stuff.

### update

There's also a trick using two C functions (probably efficient), if you're operating on a buffer.
With point *right after* `(`:

```
(read (point-marker))
=> test-func
```

The return result is a Lisp symbol, which might readily be useful.

Comment: This will also match digits (as in lists).

Comment: `\\sw` matches digits.

Comment: Well, this depends on what exactly OP means by his question: is it "how to match a function call and to extract the name of the function being called" - in which case your regexp gives extra matches, or "given that the string is know to be a function call, how to extract its name", in which case that's fine.

Comment: Thanks @abo-abo. I also found this regex : `"\\(\\w\\|\\s_\\)+"`, see https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Syntax.html

Comment: That's almost what I wrote, except you use a capturing group instead of non-capturing (less efficient), and word constituent instead of symbol constituent (might be a small difference).

Comment: `\\w` instead of `\\sw` will fail for `(str "(test-\ func123")`, which is a valid symbol.